# Грамматика после слова «взамен»

Tags: грамматика, предлоги, падежи, управление

Скажите, пожалуйста, как будет правильнее: "*Он дал мне это взамен прошлой сигарет**ы***" или "*Он дал мне это взамен прошлой сигарет**е***"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно с родительным падежом:

*Он дал мне это взамен прошлой сигарет**ы***.

> **ВЗАМЕН. I. *нареч.*** Вместо этого, в обмен. *Прислать в. кого-л. другого. Попросить что-л. в.* **II. *предлог.*** чего. Вместо. *В. урока русского языка был проведён урок истории. Выдать справку в. диплома.*

Источник: Большой толковый словарь ([Грамота.ру](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%92%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD&all=x)).